# How to compile Maven project from command line with all dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project that I can normally compile and run from eclipse but when I compile it from command line it's dependencies are missing and I'm getting errors. I can compile project only after I download dependencies and add them to c:/Java/jdk/jre/lib/ext

How can I compile project and it's dependencies from console line without adding them manually to jdk? Can compiler somehow read maven dependencies?

pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TCPPing</groupId>
  <artifactId>TCPPing</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: please consider reading at least some of the maven documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html - and please NEVER EVER add ANYTHING to lib/ext/ again! The java classpath options are enough to run you application. Dont pollute your java installation with project specific files.

Comment: I did read it and I still don't understan what to do, I am very new to all this. I managed to generate jar file of my project with all the dependencies and run it, but that is not what I need, I just want my compiler to read my dependencies from projectFolder/lib

Comment: Please add the `pom.xml` of your project

Comment: What dependencies did you need to add to JDKs ext folder? You could find the corresponding dependencies using search.maven.org and add them to your pom.

Comment: i need all dependencies from the pom.xml stated above. commons-cli, commons-net and logback-classic

Comment: 1. did you try mvn clean compile? 2. Running your program with java TCPPing would require that your main class is in the default package, which would be bad practice.

Comment: i did, doesn't help. I know it's a bad practice but it is a port of an assignment that clearly states that program must be executed in that way.

Comment: Execution is different to runtime. Please post the maven command your running to compile the application, and any error messages. Please add it to your question, not a comment.

Comment: Maven will download your dependencies to ~/.m2/repository not project/lib. It will then update the compile time classpath to point to them during compilation.

Comment: mvn clean compile works fine. says build successful. but when i run javac compile it doesnt work.

Comment: MVN compile runs javac for you, adding the dependent jars to the classpath. Did you find the class files generated into the target folder?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be quite straightforward to run your application from an IDE with some maven support (Eclipse, IntellIJ). These IDE's will take care about creating the correct classpath.

If you want to do this manually, try this:

change to the directory that contains the pom.xml
execute the maven command:

```
mvn clean install
```

This will compile your project and create the jar you defined in the pom.xml file. It runs the maven phases clean and every phase up to install (compile, test, etc).

Then collect all jar files you use as dependencies (required to run your project):

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This executes the dependency plugin which will copy all dependencies into `target/dependency`.

You can then run your main method using:

```
cd target/
java -cp TCPPing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency TCPPing
```

`-cp` defines the classpath (all locations / jar files / folders that contain classes). `TCPPing` is the class your run that has a main method.

Note the `:` is for Linux / Mac - I think windows uses a `;`.

Comment: Thank you! A bit unrelated question but do you know why my logback logger doesn't work when I run program like this? It works fine whine I run it from Eclipse, but when I run program from console it just prints log in the console but not in the file?

Comment: it probably cant find your configuration file and uses the defaults (log to console). If you follow the maven standards and put your config file into src/main/resources (I would also recommend using src/main/java as default for the java files, you have reconfigured that part) it will end up in the jar you are creating and therefore be available in the classpath. The IDE picks it up from the folder since you probably maintain a set of folders as classpath within the IDE. E.g. an IDE will pick up almost anything - not always wanted but lucky in this case.

Comment: @wemu, i was using the commands you mentioned to run a project. The console prints `Error: Could not find or load main class SocketWindowWordCount`, you think what could be the reason?

Comment: I would suggest to create a new question - your issue looks like a missing dependency or wrong classpath but from a comment it's hard to tell what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Javac knows nothing about maven. Thus it will not utilize the maven pom.xml.

The value of maven is that it removes the manual work of building, testing and releasing a project.

This includes getting dependencies, and running javac with them added to the classpath of the javac command.

You can manually execute javac after maven downloads dependencies to ~/.m2/repository. However you'll need to tell javac where to find the jars. Thus is done via the classpath argument.

If you are trying to run the project after using mvn to compile it, you'll need to do this in the same folder where your .class files were placed. Thus should be /target/java or similar.

Comment: I have /target/classes folder with all the class files. But when I open command line in that folder and run java TCPPing arguments I still get NoClassDefException