# How to compile Maven based Java project to run it from command line

Tags: java, maven, cmd, compilation, executable

I have a Maven project that I need somehow to compile so I'd be able to transfer the compiled file to a different machine and then execute there (with potentially different Java version). 
I looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315279/how-to-compile-maven-project-from-command-line-with-all-dependencies)

and was able to execute:

```
mvn clean install
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Yet when I tried:

```
cd target/
java -cp myApp-0.0.1.jar:dependency myApp
```

I got

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myApp
```

My pom.xml does not have mvn-assembly-plugin or maven-jar-plugin (and I successfully get the .jar in target/ after mvn clean install).

I am not sure whether those steps are related to my goal because what I need is  to create something that will run without any java -jar or mvn and could be ported and run on a different machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Maven build plugin that would bundle all your dependencies in a JAR. You could execute it simply with

```
java -jar mybundled.jar
```

without caring about class path dependencies.

And here comes the `Maven` plugin. Replace the `MainClass` with your entry point.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>       
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.yourdomain.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
     </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>make-assembly</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As it is bound to the `package lifecycle`, you would find your bundled JAR in your target directory after doing a ...

```
mvn package
```

Regarding your concern that your code won't run on another machine, Java is platform-independent and *generally* you can rely on that. However, three things come to my mind that can make life hard:

1. Your code depends on the system encoding. Maven should give you a warning on that in the log, advising you to specify it explicitly.
2. You interact with the runtime, like executing system commands. `ps` won't work on windows and `dir /s` probably not on *nix.
3. The version of your Java environment differ. Of course, JavaFX code won't run with a Java 1.5. If you use the latest features, make sure your clients already have the respective version or, at least, are able to get it from somewhere. You might want to take a look at the `source` and `target` compile options, too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example

Comment: Alright, all this worked, yet because I am using some config files located in `src/main/config`, I need to run the jar from the top folder in the manner `java -jar target/mybundled.jar`.  I'll see how it goes with porting it to a different machine (my concern is it my have different Java and then the .jar might not run correctly. Will it actually be possible at all to run it on such a different machine?) and then will take it as an answer

Comment: Glad I could help. I've appended a comment to my post regarding your cross-platform concerns.

Comment: Nice add. The 3rd item conveys what I was most concerned about. In my particular case, I checked `java --version` on the remote host, and it was 1.8 so there would not be a problem as of today (Jul 2016). But thank you for pointing to that link and how to address this issue in general.