# maven java.lang.NoClassDeffoundError Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, maven, command-line

i have a maven project that works on intellij idea perfectly but when i try to run it using the command line i get this error  java.lang.NoClassDeffoundError 
 i used

```
   mvn clean install 
   mvn dependency:copy-dependencies cd target/ 
   java -cp Flux-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency SocketServer
```

here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Flux</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.neovisionaries/nv-websocket-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
        <artifactId>nv-websocket-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can someone please help me with this issue thanks

Comment: Do I read it correctly - you copy files to `target` but include the directory `dependency` in the classpath?

Comment: i followed these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315279/how-to-compile-maven-project-from-command-line-with-all-dependencies

Comment: OK. Make sure you actually do `cd target` and that you use the correct path delimiter for your OS (`:` for Linux, `;` for Windows).
Also check that all the required dependencies are copied to `target/dependency`.

Comment: i chekcked everything is okay ! maybe i should check something in my pom.xml ?

Comment: So you have made sure the missing class is in the `Flux-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency` classpath?

Comment: yes all my jars ar in the dpendency file

Comment: please add error full stack trace @pintjo

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketListener
 at SocketServer.main(SocketServer.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketListener
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Answer (score 0):

With this error message `java.lang.NoClassDeffoundError` you can see that it refers to a class file that it could not found. Check from which jar package that class file belongs to. Get that jar file and put that in java class path.

Also try to run from the parent directory of your maven project like below:-

```
 java -cp target/Flux-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency SocketServer
```

Or try like below:-

```
  java -jar target/Flux-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can set the classpath like below:-

```
 CP="\path\some.jar"

 java -jar -cp $CP target/Flux-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar // but in windows %CP%
```

Comment: i guess it's a class path problem how can i proceed to add in the java class path ? i am new to this so i get confused quickly !